# servicestack Razor view pages for response dto's with same name but different namespace

Tags: servicestack

i have 2 dto's in different sub namespaces but the same class name for response dto, in the same assembly.

with the razor view pages in servicestack, it looks for the response dto .cshtml in the View folder.

is it possible to have 2 separate razor view pages for different namespaces?

eg

```
namespace mydto.Cars
{
      public class queryResponse
      {
      }
}

namespace mydto.Bikes
{
      public class queryResponse
      {
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it scans for view pages by name only. I would add the namespace tail to the DTO that describes how the DTO is different, e.g. CarsQueryResponse.

With ServiceStack in general you don't want to have multiple DTOs with the same name but different namespaces, e.g. Every Request DTO must be unique by name, this is what allows you to call a web service knowing the name only.